# How to add more than 1 cookie on Mule?

Tags: cookies, mule

I was able to add just 1 cookie through Mule ESB on the response of the request. However, when I try to add more than 1 cookie, with the property "Set-Cookie", Mule overrides the first cookie and just returns the second one.

For example, on the below snippet code I have added 2 cookies on the message property (which is a map).

```
`String msg =  "SSID=123;domain=localhost;Path=/";
 String msg2 =  "SSAPID=456;domain=localhost;Path=/";
 message.setProperty(HttpHeaders.Names.SET_COOKIE,msg, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);
 message.setProperty(HttpHeaders.Names.SET_COOKIE,msg2, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);
`
```

And when I catched the response, there was only one cookie:

```
  Message properties:
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    Set-Cookie=SAPID=456
    access-control-allow-credentials=true
    access-control-allow-headers=Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache, X-Auth-Token
    access-control-allow-methods=PATCH, PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
    access-control-allow-origin=*
    access-control-max-age=10
    cache-control=no-store
    content-encoding=gzip
    content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8
    date=Wed, 13 Jan 2016 12:26:58 GMT
    http.reason=OK
    http.status=200
    pragma=no-cache
    server=Apache-Coyote/1.1
    transfer-encoding=chunked
    vary=[Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding]
    x-content-type-options=nosniff
    x-xss-protections=1; mode=block
  SESSION scoped properties:
```

**Set-Cookie**=SAPID=456

As you can see, only the second cookie was returned on the request.

How can I achieve what I want to do, since the spec of the cookie, described here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3.1 says that I can return more than 1 Set-Cookie on the response header.

> The server can store a session
> identifier as well as the user's preferred language by returning two
> Set-Cookie header fields

Comment: Which mule version are you using? HTTP transport (inbound/outbound) or connector (listener/request)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the same property twice it will just override it. Instead add the property once but set the value to a list:

```
List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<String>();
cookies.add(msg1);
cookies.add(msg2);

 message.setProperty(HttpHeaders.Names.SET_COOKIE,cookies, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);
```

Returns:

```
curl http://localhost:8087/test -i
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Length: 3
Set-Cookie: SSAPID=456;domain=localhost;Path=/
Set-Cookie: SSID=123;domain=localhost;Path=/
Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 15:09:54 GMT
```